# Realm not deleting correctly

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, realm

I have two Realm Object Classe:

```
class OrderItemList: Object {
let ListofStockItemOrderData = List<OrderItem>()
    //
}

class OrderItem: Object {
    dynamic var UnitDescriptor = " "
    dynamic var StockQty = 0
    dynamic var StockItemUnique = Int()
    dynamic var StockUnitCost = Int()
    dynamic var isCompleted = false
}
```

I add and save items to `OrderItem` and then display it in a `UITableView` , I delete unwanted items I added by :

```
var dataToBeUsed : Results<OrderItem>!

let itemToBeDelete = dataToBeUsed[indexPath.row]     
    try! realm.write {
        realm.delete(itemToBeDelete)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

When I call :

```
let allObjects = realm.objects(OrderItemList.self)
```

The Items I deleted are gone, but When I call:

```
let allObjects = realm.objects(OrderItem.self)
```

The Items are still there.
How do I delete them from both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I'd recommend removing `tableView.reloadData()` out of the `realm.write` block and placing it below. This will make sure the item is properly deleted before reloading the table view.

Hmm, it sounds like you're deleting the object from the parent list, but not properly from Realm. Realm doesn't [support cascading deletes](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1186) yet, so it's necessary for you to directly delete the target objects (The `OrderItem` object. Removing it from `OrderItemList`, or deleting `OrderItemList` won't do it), instead of deleting any lists they belong to.

Did that make sense? Let me know if you need more clarification!

Comment: How do I do this if I may ask? Sorry this is my first time using realm

Comment: No worries! It's nothing out of the ordinary. Just make sure you're calling `realm.delete` directly on the exact `OrderItem` object you want to delete. Doing it on the list object that's holding the object in an array isn't enough.